# Grand Total in Group by Clause

Tags: sql, group-by

I am learning sql and stuck in a situation where I want grand total of a row as follows

[image: I want output like this]

Following is the query I have written to achieve this but did not make it.

```
SELECT e.Name,e.[Year],count(e.Name) AS total
FROM dbo.Employee e
GROUP BY e.Name,e.[Year] with rollup
```

but this query results included null values also which I don't want.

[image: Result]

How want grand total of **total column**. How can I achieve that.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `grouping sets`:

```
SELECT COALESCE(e.Name, 'Total') as name, e.[Year], count(e.Name) AS total
FROM dbo.Employee e
GROUP BY GROUPING SETS ((e.Name, e.[Year]), ()) ;
```

Most databases that support `with rollup` also support `grouping sets`.

This uses `COALESCE()` as a convenient way to put `'Total'` in the column.  If `Name` can be `NULL`, then you need better logic.

Comment: and how to write Total with at the end of result.